# Why is my new screen upside down and mirrored?

Tags: screen, hardware

I broke and replaced the screen on my Nexus 5.

Once I booted the phone up, the new screen is upsidedown and mirrored, also touch doesn't work at all.

I can see how the touchpart is caused by a broken connector or something, but the mirroring?

Comment: Any change that you reversed the connector?

Comment: @JanDoggen Nice idea, but that's no it unfortunately. The screen only fits one way, so the connector can't be put in upside down.